# how to populate torch::jit::IValue with C++ array without using torch::from_blob

Tags: c++, libtorch

I have an array that I want to convert to `torch::jit::IValue` and this seems to do the trick:

```
auto torch_options = torch::TensorOptions().dtype(torch::kFloat32).device(device);
torch::Tensor my_tensor = torch::from_blob(
          my_array.begin(),
          {3, 20},
          torch_options); 
std::vector<torch::jit::IValue> my_input;
my_input.push_back(my_tensor);
auto output = model.forward(my_input).toTensor();
```

This works but is there a way I could convert my array directly to `torch::jit::IValue` without having to convert it to `torch::Tensor`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `torch::jit::IValue::from` to convert a raw pointer to an `IValue`:

```
auto my_array = std::vector<float>{1, 2, 3};
auto my_input = std::vector<torch::jit::IValue>{torch::jit::IValue::from(my_array.data())};
```

Comment: is there any way I can specify start and end of the array? Also my libtorch version doesn't seem to have `torch::jit::IValue::from`... I'm using the most recent one.

Comment: I think you can use the following:
std::vector<int> vec = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
auto t = torch::from_blob(vec.data(), vec.size(), torch::kInt32);